OpenOffice/Libre Office Calc - counting how many records contains non-empty fields
I was forced to use Calc instead of my beloved, well-known Excel, because open source, free, yada yada yada.
And need help. I have a table with the structure:
Column A - group name;
column B - subgroups - from 1 to 7 per group;
Columns C to CF are event days with work hours.
I need just to count how many subgroups in each group work in a particular year (table).
So if any work hours field in range C:AF is bigger than 0, it means that the subgroup works in that year (at least one time). My result should be single number per each group, ie. 5 for Group A,0 for Group C, etc.
Have you any idea how to calculate it in an elegant way (by that I mean a way that allow me just to drag down the formula), without writing a very large formulas with multiple nested "countif() and sum()?
I was trying with sum.product(), but dunno how to use it in that case.
Any tip?

I suggest to [edit] your question and create a table that shows a simplified example how your spreadsheet looks like. Explain what result you want to get based on your example. If you know how to do it in Excel, adding the Excel formula might also help. Otherwise mentioning Excel is distracting and should be removed from the question.

This is an array formula, so

select enough number of cells to hold the result

enter the following in the first cell cell

press Control + Shift + Enter (Windows) or Command + Shift + Enter (Mac)

in the example I selected A13:B15, entered the formula in A13 and adjusted range to omit #N/A values


=LET(
    hours, C2:CF9,
    group_and_sub, A2:B9,
    sum_hours, MMULT(hours + 0, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(hours), , , 0)),
    with_active_subs, FILTER(group_and_sub, sum_hours),
    u_group, UNIQUE(INDEX(with_active_subs, , 1)),
    u_row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(u_group)),
    sub_group_count, INDEX(
        FREQUENCY(XMATCH(INDEX(with_active_subs, , 1), u_group), u_row_indices),
        u_row_indices,
        1
    ),
    CHOOSE({1, 2}, u_group, sub_group_count)
)


FREQUENCY returns number of items in the bins + 1, so by using INDEX(freq, u_row_indices,1) we drop the last row
Since HSTACK is not available, we can use CHOOSE to place arrays side by side


